# Spectral theorem and inequality

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

I will be very grateful if someone tell me why $\|(1-e^{t L})(t L)^{-b/2}(t L)^{b/2}\|_2$ is controled by $\|(t L)^{b/2}\|_2$ were $L$ is a self-adjoint operator and $t>0$.

[image]

Please see here https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0022247X06010377?token=14DF70907A3A1D7C9769738A2DC68D24527707D5082CED7B5341CCFED2952492448FCC435FD72F1A377E3A499AC124EB&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20210809210201
(Proof of theorem 3.1.)
My Proof. One has $L=\int \lambda d\lambda$ so
$\|(1-e^{t L})(t L)^{-b/2}(t L)^{b/2}\|^2_2=\int |(1-e^{t \lambda})(t \lambda)^{-b/2}(t \lambda)^{b/2}|^2 d\lambda\leq C\int (t \lambda)^{b/2}|^2 d\lambda=C\|(t L)^{b/2}\|^2_2$.
Is it true?

Comment: The idea you should have in mind is that $g(A)$ for a selfadjoint operator $A$ is that you diagonalize $A$ and replace every eigenvalue $\lambda$ by $g(\lambda)$ (at least if the spectrum consists only of eigenvalues). Hence, if $g$ is bounded, then all eigenvalues of $g(A)$ will be bounded and thus $g(A)$ will be bounded too. To make all of this handwaving chit-chatting rigorous one invokes the spectral theorem.

Comment: This looks like a question that can be made self-contained.

Comment: @QuantumSpace. I can't do it, Please could do it

Comment: Thank you @SeverinSchraven.

Comment: First note that this is not true for all self-adjoint $L$, you need $L$ to be negative (or at least bounded from above). Your proof goes in the right direction, but it is technically not quite correct: The spectral theorem asserts $L=\int \lambda\,d E(\lambda)$ for some projection-valued measure $E$ (what you wrote down is a scalar expression). Moreover, you are missing a bunch of $f$'s in your norm expressions, and the $f$ should also go into your integral.

Comment: That being said, I agree with QuantumSpace. This question could take some polishing. I don't think the content of the image is really necessary, but if you want to include it, writing it in mathjax would make the question more accessible. Also, please state the setting and the conditions on $f, L$ etc. explicitly in the beginning. Finally, I find the 4-line URL rather distracting. Giving the source is of course very much appreciated, but you might hide the URL behind the title and author of the paper (links can rot, but articles are typically still around).

Comment: Thank you for your message@Maowao. $L$ is a  positive self adjoint operator. Please could help me